# JSON Query Does Not Update TextView

Tags: java, android, json, textview

I have 3 textviews which I am attempting to update with data pulled via JSON - I'm not getting any errors with what I've built so far - but the textviews (nameTv, contentTv and publishedTv) don't seem to update with the data from my JSON query.

```
public class Player extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        String uploader = getIntent().getStringExtra("uploader");
        String viewCount = getIntent().getStringExtra("viewCount");
        TextView titleTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
        TextView uploaderTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uploaderTv);
        TextView viewCountTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewCountTv);
        titleTv.setText(title);
        uploaderTv.setText("by" + uploader + " |");
        viewCountTv.setText(viewCount + " views");
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
        GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask task = new GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask(null, viewCount);
        task.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onInitializationFailure()",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            String video_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
            player.loadVideo(video_id);
        }
    }

    public final class GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public static final String LIBRARY = "CommentsLibrary";
        private final Handler replyTo;
        private final String username;
        String video_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

        public GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask(Handler replyTo, String username) {
            this.replyTo = replyTo;
            this.username = username;
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(
                        "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"
                                + video_id
                                + "/comments?v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=true");

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

                String jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response
                        .getEntity().getContent());

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray(
                        "items");

                List<Comments> comments = new ArrayList<Comments>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String content = jsonObject.getString("content");
                    String published = jsonObject.getString("published");

                    comments.add(new Comments(name, content, published));

                    TextView nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                    nameTv.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));

                    TextView contentTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
                    contentTv.setText(jsonObject.getString("content"));

                    TextView publishedTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.published);
                    publishedTv.setText(jsonObject.getString("published"));

                }

                CommentsLibrary lib = new CommentsLibrary(username, comments);

                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                data.putSerializable(LIBRARY, lib);

                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.setData(data);
                replyTo.sendMessage(msg);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e("Feck", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Feck", e);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Feck", e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the UI in `doInBackground()` -- please see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You will need to deliver the results to `onPostExecute()` and handle your UI updates there.